# Data type mismatch in criteria expression c# Oledb access database

Tags: c#, oledb

I'm getting data type mismatch in criteria expression  error when i execute this code....

```
cmd.CommandText = "insert into Exams values(@p1,@p2,@p3,@p4,@p5,@p6)";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", txtexamname.Text);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Convert.ToInt32( txtnumofque.Text));
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", dtp1.Value);                           
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", cats);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p5", allques);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p6", txtexaminer.Text);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: What is your _complete_ error message? What are your column types in `Exams` table and what are the types of your values that you supply as a parameter?

Comment: Also, post DDL for your `Exams` table.

Comment: Also don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. [It *may* generate unexpected and surprising results sometimes](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/). Use `Add` method overload to specify your parameter type and it's size.